# Best practice for ignoring touch events for specific amount of time?

Tags: android

android newbie here...

I have a working program that responds to user touches on the screen. The code responds to the initial ACTION_DOWN with an animation and then responds to the ACTION_UP with a second animation.

I would like to ignore touches for a period of time after the ACTION_UP to prevent the user from starting a new animation before the second animation finishes.

What is the best way to implement this... disable focus with a timer?... intercept the touches?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Remember your current animation in a class variable and ignore the touch input in the corresponding listener as long as your animation has not finished.
You can check whether the animation is finished via the [Animation.hasEnded()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#hasEnded%28%29) method.

Comment: thanks for the answer!  I am not using an actual animation, but rather a simple canvas method that draws one thing for Action_Down and another thing for Action_Up. This looks like an animation to the user. I'm not sure how to ignore the touch event.

Comment: As long as you know how long the animation takes you can ignore touch events by placing them in an `if(notAnimating)` statement.